# Android NDK installation issues

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to install the NDK bundle in Android Studio 2.0 (beta). Following [this official link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview). The zip file gets downloaded completely, but it gets stuck while unzipping some file `mtd.h`. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

It's stuck here for about 30 minutes by now. I tried cancelling and redownloading, but the unzipping process always gets stuck at the same place. Any ideas upon why is it happening?

Comment: Have you checked that the install path has appropriate read/write permissions?

Comment: Didn't check any further. I'll check and update. This was android studio 2.0 beta 6 version. I switched to android studio 1.4 and it worked out there.

Comment: I had the same problem with ndk 12. It was stuck on the very end of progress bar on some .h file. It finally ended 2 hours later!

Comment: Stuck for me at posix_types.h with Android Studio 2.0

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a bug in Android Studio. If you want to file a bug report, there are some instructions for doing so [here](http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs/studio). You can always [download the NDK](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) separately and move it to the ndk-bundle location manually.

Comment: I agree there might be a bug, however, if you download the NDK separately you can only get up to NDK rc11c, so far did not find any NDK 12 versions downloadable from outside the SDK manager.

Comment: Hm, where are you trying to download from? NDK 12 is available for download from the NDK Downloads page here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

Comment: You are right @Francesca, the download page I found in my search is outdated.

Comment: how about the downloaded file https://dl.google.com/android/repository ? I think those components are valid as well when manually downloading and installing using SDK Manager?

Comment: for the NDK specifically for instance https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r15c-darwin-x86_64.zip

Answer (score 2):

Tried it again, this time with Android Studio 2.1. It got stuck again at some .h file. I left it the way it was and after about 30 minutes, the unzipping was successfully completed and the NDK was updated.

I keep having the similar issue everytime I update NDK. You might have to wait for upto 2 hours, but it does gets updated eventually.

Comment: I can confirm that, had to wait for 20-30 minutes but it got finished

Comment: Same here. It really can take up to an hour.